# Pa_GetStreamTime is returning 0 time

Tags: c++, qt, portaudio

I am reading audio wav files using PortAudio. The callback function is working fine and the files are being played OK in Ubunto as it should. The issue is when I try to get the time using Pa_GetStreamTime as it returns 0, I have been reading portaudio documentation and examples but I could not find a way to troubleshoot or at least an example using that function. I went through the API documentation [here](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#a2b3fb60e6949f37f7f134105ff425749) but nothing rings the bell yet. If anyone can provide a hint, it would be much appreciated. Below is  the implementation part where the callback function is taking place,  I am using Qt as my final goal is displaying the FTT of any wav file. Thanks in advance.

```
int playAudio::patestCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                       unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                       const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                       PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                       void *userData)
{

    /* Cast data passed through stream to our structure. */
    //  data = (WAV*)userData;
    float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;
    (void) inputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warning. */

    /*terminates the stream flows and reset cursor.*/
    if (cursor == playAudio::SubChunk2Size / 4)
    {
        cursor = 0;
        return paComplete;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < framesPerBuffer; i++)
    {
        if (cursor == playAudio::SubChunk2Size / 4) break; // breaks if samples reached last.
        *(out++) = pLeftChannel[cursor];
        *(out++) = pRightChannel[cursor];
        cursor++;

    }
    //  qDebug()<<cursor;
    playAudio::audioTime = Pa_GetStreamTime(stream);
    qDebug() << playAudio::audioTime;
    return paContinue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html) for the PortAudio audio callback:

> Before we begin, it's important to realize that the callback is a
>   delicate place. This is because some systems perform the callback in a
>   special thread, or interrupt handler, and it is rarely treated the
>   same as the rest of your code. For most modern systems, you won't be
>   able to cause crashes by making disallowed calls in the callback, but
>   if you want your code to produce glitch-free audio, you will have to
>   make sure you avoid function calls that may take an unbounded amount
>   of time to execute. Exactly what these are depend on your platform but
>   almost certainly include the following: memory
>   allocation/deallocation, I/O **(including file I/O as well as console
>   I/O, such as printf())**, context switching (such as exec() or yield()),
>   mutex operations, or anything else that might rely on the OS. If you
>   think short critical sections are safe please go read about priority
>   inversion. Windows amd Mac OS schedulers have no real-time safe
>   priority inversion prevention. Other platforms require special mutex
>   flags. **In addition, it is not safe to call any PortAudio API functions
>   in the callback except as explicitly permitted in the documentation.**

Emphasis mine.

In other words, calling `Pa_GetStreamTime()` from within the callback is undefined behavior. But you don't need to call that function in the first place. Why?  Because the fourth parameter to the callback is a [PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/structPaStreamCallbackTimeInfo.html) struct, which contains the very same timing information you're trying to access.

Additionally, that `qDebug` call will likely screw up your audio playback. Writing to stdout simply takes too long to complete inside a realtime audio callback.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I tried that structure PaStreamCall... before because I did not want to mess the callback function but in the currentTime member, I got 0s; using the outputBufferDACtime I could see data time but not sure how to handle that, I add them up but the result didnt make sense so tried  Pa_getStreamTime giving the same result when I used the currentTime. About qDebug you are right, in my case is not giving issues, eventually will be deleted. If you can share info using the portaudio and getting the time or know how to handle that data from the timeInfo.OutputBufferDACTime.